# How can I control the order of pivoted (wider) columns in R? tidyverse issue 839

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I can pivot the data in wider format if the values to be pivoted consist in more than one column.

```
us_rent_income %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = variable,
    names_glue = "{variable}_{.value}",
    values_from = c(estimate, moe)
  )

# A tibble: 52 x 6
   GEOID NAME                 income_estimate rent_estimate income_moe rent_moe
   <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 01    Alabama                        24476           747        136        3
 2 02    Alaska                         32940          1200        508       13
 3 04    Arizona                        27517           972        148        4
 4 05    Arkansas                       23789           709        165        5
 5 06    California                     29454          1358        109        3
 6 08    Colorado                       32401          1125        109        5
 7 09    Connecticut                    35326          1123        195        5
 8 10    Delaware                       31560          1076        247       10
 9 11    District of Columbia           43198          1424        681       17
10 12    Florida                        25952          1077         70        3
# ... with 42 more rows
```

In this code output, I want the order of columns to be `income_estimate`, `income_moe`, `rent_estimate` and `rent_moe`.  Setting `names_sort = T` isn't helping.  Changing the order in `names_glue` doesn't help either.  I know I can reorder columns by `select` and through other functions, but I just want to know that is there any argument in `pivot_wider` to do so?

**EDIT** the issue seems already in development; it has been discussed [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/839) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1064) at least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the advent of [tidyr 1.2.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/02/tidyr-1-2-0/), it is now super easy with the use of argument `names_vary`

```r
library(tidyr)
us_rent_income %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = variable,
    names_glue = "{variable}_{.value}",
    values_from = c(estimate, moe),
    names_vary = 'slowest'
  )
#> # A tibble: 52 x 6
#>    GEOID NAME                 income_estimate income_moe rent_estimate rent_moe
#>    <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 01    Alabama                        24476        136           747        3
#>  2 02    Alaska                         32940        508          1200       13
#>  3 04    Arizona                        27517        148           972        4
#>  4 05    Arkansas                       23789        165           709        5
#>  5 06    California                     29454        109          1358        3
#>  6 08    Colorado                       32401        109          1125        5
#>  7 09    Connecticut                    35326        195          1123        5
#>  8 10    Delaware                       31560        247          1076       10
#>  9 11    District of Columbia           43198        681          1424       17
#> 10 12    Florida                        25952         70          1077        3
#> # ... with 42 more rows
```

The explanation of `names_vary` given at package help page is -

`names_vary`
When `names_from` identifies a column (or columns) with multiple unique values, and multiple `values_from` columns are provided, in what order should the resulting column names be combined?

- "fastest" varies `names_from` values fastest, resulting in a column naming scheme of the form: `value1_name1`, `value1_name2`, `value2_name1`, `value2_name2`. This is the default.
- `"slowest"` varies `names_from` values slowest, resulting in a column naming scheme of the form: `value1_name1`, `value2_name1`, `value1_name2`, `value2_name2`.

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it would be nice to see some more explanation for why it works as the argument name isn't very intuitive, to me at least.

Comment: I am not sure copying the help page is very helpful. In my opinion the answer would be clearer if you explained that setting `names_vary` to "slowest" ensures that columns are ordered after the column where the names (income, rent) are coming from, and not after the columns that the values are coming from (estimate and moe in this case). This explanation can be directly linked to the column order OP is after, and therefore explains why setting `names_vary` works in this particular case. But I might be over-complicating things!

Comment: @mafw, yes as default value of `names_vary` gives results as already given in question.  That's why I thought it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

For fine-grained control, you can use `pivot_wider_spec()`, which lets you define the specification for the resulting data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

spec <- tibble(
  .name = c("income_estimate", "income_moe", "rent_estimate", "rent_moe"),
  .value = c("estimate", "moe", "estimate", "moe"),
  variable = c("income", "income", "rent", "rent")
)

us_rent_income %>% pivot_wider_spec(spec)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 52 x 6
   GEOID NAME                 income_estimate income_moe rent_estimate rent_moe
   <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 01    Alabama                        24476        136           747        3
 2 02    Alaska                         32940        508          1200       13
 3 04    Arizona                        27517        148           972        4
 4 05    Arkansas                       23789        165           709        5
 5 06    California                     29454        109          1358        3
 6 08    Colorado                       32401        109          1125        5
 7 09    Connecticut                    35326        195          1123        5
 8 10    Delaware                       31560        247          1076       10
 9 11    District of Columbia           43198        681          1424       17
10 12    Florida                        25952         70          1077        3
# … with 42 more rows
```

And with a few pre-processing steps, you can avoid having to manually enter all the values in `spec`:

```r
field <- us_rent_income %>% distinct(variable) %>% pull()
sub_field <- colnames(us_rent_income)[4:5]

pivot_names <- map(field, ~paste(., sub_field, sep = "_")) %>% unlist()
pivot_vals <- rep(sub_field, 2)
pivot_vars <- map(field, rep, 2) %>% unlist()

spec <- tibble(.name = pivot_names, .value = pivot_vals, variable = pivot_vars)

us_rent_income %>% pivot_wider_spec(spec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort sir :)  There can be many workarounds.  However, I was particularly looking for the direct method if it can be done through `pivot_wider` only.  In `Excel`, `tableau` etc. this is very easy as `values` pill just need to be shifted before or after `names`.  See the discussion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/839)

Answer (score 2):

After the pivoting, we could do a `select` by `order`ing the substring of column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr0
us_rent_income %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = variable,
    names_glue = "{variable}_{.value}",
    values_from = c(estimate, moe)
 ) %>%
  select(GEOID, NAME, order(str_remove(names(.)[-(1:2)], "_.*")) + 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 52 x 6
#   GEOID NAME                 income_estimate income_moe rent_estimate rent_moe
#   <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 01    Alabama                        24476        136           747        3
# 2 02    Alaska                         32940        508          1200       13
# 3 04    Arizona                        27517        148           972        4
# 4 05    Arkansas                       23789        165           709        5
# 5 06    California                     29454        109          1358        3
# 6 08    Colorado                       32401        109          1125        5
# 7 09    Connecticut                    35326        195          1123        5
# 8 10    Delaware                       31560        247          1076       10
# 9 11    District of Columbia           43198        681          1424       17
#10 12    Florida                        25952         70          1077        3
# … with 42 more rows
```

---

The `order`ing is based on the `names_from` column and so the `names_sort` have no impact on the column names from `values_from` i.e. in the OP's solution, it wouldn't change if we change the order in `names_glue`.  In the data, the 'variable' column `unique` value appearance is in `income`, followed by `rent`.  So, it does that order, when the default `names_sort = FALSE`.  If it is changed to `TRUE`, it does alphabetic order, which is again `i` followed by `r`.

It can be checked if we first reshape to 'long', `unite` the columns and then do the `pivot_wider`

```
us_rent_income %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(estimate, moe)) %>% 
  unite(variable, variable, name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 52 x 6
#   GEOID NAME                 income_estimate income_moe rent_estimate rent_moe
#   <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 01    Alabama                        24476        136           747        3
# 2 02    Alaska                         32940        508          1200       13
# 3 04    Arizona                        27517        148           972        4
# 4 05    Arkansas                       23789        165           709        5
# 5 06    California                     29454        109          1358        3
# 6 08    Colorado                       32401        109          1125        5
# 7 09    Connecticut                    35326        195          1123        5
# 8 10    Delaware                       31560        247          1076       10
# 9 11    District of Columbia           43198        681          1424       17
#10 12    Florida                        25952         70          1077        3
# … with 42 more rows
```

---

Now, we check by changing into custom order with `factor` and specify `names_sort = TRUE`, it will go in the order we wanted

```
us_rent_income %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = c(estimate, moe)) %>% 
   unite(variable, variable, name) %>%
   mutate(variable = factor(variable, 
    levels = c('income_estimate', 'rent_moe', 'rent_estimate', 'income_moe'))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value, names_sort = TRUE)
# A tibble: 52 x 6
#   GEOID NAME                 income_estimate rent_moe rent_estimate income_moe
#   <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 01    Alabama                        24476        3           747        136
# 2 02    Alaska                         32940       13          1200        508
# 3 04    Arizona                        27517        4           972        148
# 4 05    Arkansas                       23789        5           709        165
# 5 06    California                     29454        3          1358        109
# 6 08    Colorado                       32401        5          1125        109
# 7 09    Connecticut                    35326        5          1123        195
# 8 10    Delaware                       31560       10          1076        247
# 9 11    District of Columbia           43198       17          1424        681
#10 12    Florida                        25952        3          1077         70
# … with 42 more rows
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal Sorry, I was not sure whether you meant manually doing `select` or programmatically as in my code

Comment: @AnilGoyal Also, if you check the `spec` answer, it is also a manual reordering similar to a `select` approach you can do manually

Comment: @AnilGoyal Based on the info in the documentation, `Should the column names be sorted? If FALSE, the default, column names are ordered by first appearance.`. I think what it meant is for sorting for individual columns values, rather than across multiple column

Comment: @AnilGoyal In this data, if you check the order of occurrence, it is `income`, followed by `rent` for the first 2 rows.  So, when you do `names_sort = FALSE`, it triggers that order.  But, if it is TRUE, it would do the alphabetic sort, which is again `i` comes before `r`

Comment: @AnilGoyal It is sorting, but it is based on the 'variable' values and not based on the column names in `values_from`

Comment: @AnilGoyal because it is based on the 'variable' column

Comment: @AnilGoyal You can check my update.  If you create a column of names by first pivoting to long, it would work in the way you wanted

Comment: Checked it. Thanks.  Indeed Easier than other workarounds, in case of many col pairs when pivoting. :)  the issue seems under notice of developer as evident from [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/839)

Comment: Could you please explain more about this part `order(str_remove(names(.)[-(1:2)], "_.*")) + 2)`?  I assume that `+2` at the end refers to 2 columns per suffix. What's about `[-(1:2)]? What if my column names have multiple "_"?

Comment: @hnguyen because we are ordering by removing the first two columns and the index from order begins from 1, adding 2 to it, forces the index to start from 3, thus acounting for the 2 columns that are not used